# Oil sump bolt: blue-loctite... too tight, even with leverage. What now?

Tags: oil, threadlocker, plug, sump

Busy doing an oil change. I have inserted engine flush, and now am ready to drain. But....

I have tried loosening this oil-sump bolt/plug and it is going absolutely nowhere unless I'm prepared to push my tools over the edge.

What is the next step? Do I need to apply heat? How should I safely do this? I don't have a blow-torch but I could get a low-budget one. Or is there anything else that is safe to use? What about a lighter? It is an open flame so I'm not very confident to try that yet.

Only other thing I can think to try is a soldering iron.

[image]

Comment: I don’t want to sound condescending, but you are turning it anti-clockwise, viewed from below?

Comment: Yep. Fair question. From below I'm turning it anti-clockwise.

Comment: In the interests of time.... we are heading into overnight territory, here, so is it safe to leave the flush in overnight?

Comment: Does the engine flush say anything about leaving it in too long?  I don’t ever use engine flush, I think it can do more harm than good, since the deposits you disturb will be pumped to all the smallest oil ways in the engine.

Comment: No. It just says add to warm engine, Idle for 15 mins before draining and filling with new oil. And it says do not drive (with the flush in). I'm going to have to back it out of the garage for the night though.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of heat you would probably need to apply, probably wouldn’t be a good idea applying to the sump.  The oil will absorb the heat, which could quickly get to ignition temperatures.

I think I would check availability of a replacement sump before forcing the plug out with a breaker bar.

If you are worried about damaging the sump, it is often possible to pump the old oil out via the dipstick tube, a lot of garages do it this way to save getting underneath the vehicle.

Comment: Ok. So, how would I do this?

Comment: Do you mean pump the oil out? - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70zR_Doi1ag

Comment: Ok. That's one temporary solution, so thanks, Howie. I'm going to see if I can try to get some local advice before resorting to this method as I'm concerned about residual oil beyond the reach of the tube.

Comment: I eventually siphoned the oil out. Went with the cheaper option, until I can source some options for forcing the sump plug loose.

Comment: Old oil manually siphoned out of the engine, and replaced with new oil. I ofc still have the problem of a stuck sump plug/screw. But good advice to source a replacement sump & plug (you were referring to both, right, Howie?)

Comment: Yes, if you damage the sump trying to get the sump plug out, then you will be stuck without a vehicle until you can fix it. If you can get a reasonably cheap sump and plug from a breakers then you are ready to replace the sump if the worst happens.  You will obviously need a sump gasket too.  You could also just continue doing oil changes by removing the oil through the dipstick, its up to you.