# Oil change drain plug

Tags: oil-change, charger

So im tryna do my oil change on my 2008 charger but i cannot get the bolt to go loose ive tried everything and im not tryna stripe it n leave it round

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please click EDIT below your question and explain what you mean by ***"ive tried everything."*** Please say what you have tried and what tools you have used. Have you already started rounding the bolt head by using something other than a proper wrench? You can add a photo by clicking EDIT, then click the icon that looks like a mountain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/94077/oil-sump-bolt-blue-loctite-too-tight-even-with-leverage-what-now/94079#94079

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried it with a impact / drill? if nothing works you can still take it to a shop and they should be able to do it.

Comment: An impact is probably the last thing you'd want to use. The oil pan is most likely aluminum, which means if you use an impact, you're going to pull all the threads out with the bolt. Definitely not a way to go.